# How to Pass Html Input value(Html Form) to java controller ? - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to use normal Html tags with Spring MVC instead of spring Html tags
but I am unable to get the input value to Controller using simple html tags.

Below is my Code:-

**Controller :**

```
@Controller
public class LoginService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authenticateUser(Model model,@ModelAttribute("userName") String userName, 
            @ModelAttribute("password") String password) {
        System.out.println("coming in controller    " +userName +" : "+ password);  
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "success";
    }
```

**JSP :**

```
<body>
<h2>${message}</h2>
<form action="authenticate.htm">
    <table>
        <caption>
            <h3>Enter Your Login Credentials</h3>
        </caption>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="userName"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowspan="2">
            <td><input type="submit"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RequestParam` instead of `ModelAttribute`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authenticateUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password ,Model model) {
        System.out.println("coming in controller    " +userName +" : "+ password);  
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "success";
    }
```

you have to change the action url of the form in jsp:

```
<form action="/authenticate">
```

update your web.xml with the following line:

```
<url-pattern>/url-pattern>
```

Comment: I am Getting Http 404 
"HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'userName' is not present" 

 and description is " The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Required String parameter 'userName' is not present).

"

Comment: clear cache of your browser and try with updated code

Comment: I cleared cache and runned the project again without changing form action ..but it was showing same exception

Comment: If I modified the form action them current servlet mapping will not work ...right?

Comment: have you tried <form action="/authenticate"> in jsp? and post your mapping xml file..

Comment: update your servlet mapping like :    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: i placed my project on github. you can download it and check.
https://github.com/svmgarg/StudentPortal

Comment: Please set "name" to all input type text and use it.
Example:
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">